# open pdf docs in from angular app on device

Tags: cordova, iframe

I am trying to develop a page that I can provide to my client so they can simply include the page as an `iframe` in their existing angular app. I need to list `docs` and `allo` the user to open the `pdf` doc on the app from the page I am serving in the `iframe`.

I am using `$cordovaFileTransfer` to get download the file from the server and `$cordovaFileOpener2` to try and open the file on the device which works fine if build my app but when I try and serve it as in an `Iframe` I get a `"Cordova is not defined"` error, so it seems `cordova` is not accessible from the `iframe` even though it is running on the parent page. Is there another way to approach this?

This is the function that is called when the user clicks to view the file, which as I mentioned works perfectly if I build the as a stand alone app:

```
$scope.getFile = function(){
        if(window.cordova){
            var url = $scope.url;
            var filename = url.split("/").pop();
            alert(filename);
            var targetPath = cordova.file.externalRootDirectory + filename;
            var trustHosts = true;
            var options = {};
            alert(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory);
            $cordovaFileTransfer.download(url, targetPath, options, trustHosts)
                .then(function(result) {
                    // Success!
                    console.log('here1: ',JSON.stringify(result));
                    //alert(JSON.stringify(result));
                    $cordovaFileOpener2.open(
                            targetPath,
                            'application/pdf'
                        ).then(function() {
                            console.log('Success here');
                        }, function(err) {
                            console.log('An error occurred here: ' + JSON.stringify(err));
                        });
                }, function(error) {
                    // Error
                    console.log('here2: ',JSON.stringify(error));
                    //alert(JSON.stringify(error));
                }, function (progress) {
                    $timeout(function () {
                        $scope.downloadProgress = (progress.loaded / progress.total) * 100;
                    })
                });
        }else{
            alert('Error: Cordova is not defined');
        }
```

Comment: try to serve means what are you trying to do ? running in browser or else ?

Comment: Hi, it will be an iframe loading inside the clients Angular app running on a mobile device

Comment: for which device are you trying? android,ios or windows one?